# MySQL call procedure with output parameter from C++ mysqlpp

Tags: c++, mysql

I need help with the C++ mysqlpp driver calling a stored procedure and retrieving its output parameter. The queries seem to pass successfully but trying to get the stored value causes segmentation fault. My current pseudo code is:

```
mysqlpp::Connection* connection; // the connection type I am bound to use, no createStatement, prepareStatement methods
Query query = connection->query();
Query transactionQuery = connection->query();
query << "CALL sp_get_transactions_count(" << inputId << ", @transactionsCount);";
transactionQuery << "SELECT @transactionsCount as combinations;";
ClearQuerySentry cleanUpQuery(transactionQuery);

query.exec();
mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult transactionsResult = transactionQuery.store();
if (!transactionsResult || transactionsResult.num_rows() == 0)
{
        logWarning(....);
}
else
{
        const mysqlpp::Row& transactionRecord = result[0];
        environment.pairTransactionsCount = verboseLexicalCast<int>(transactionRecord, "combinations"); // segfault on trying to cast static_cast<const char*>(row[fieldName.c_str()]))
}
```

I am not very experienced with mysqlpp and MySQL as a whole so it is possible my perception of the solution to be wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I assume that with result in the else branch you actually mean transactionsResult ?

Comment: Omg I can't believe I did not see that! That is the probably it,this is a monstrous method which has result above. 10x!